# How can I loop through a Perl array of arrays of hashes?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I would like to print an Array of Arrays of Hashes, so I looked at [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-ARRAYS), and ended up with

```
for my $j (0 .. $#aoaoh) {
    for my $aref (@aoaoh) {
    print '"' . join('","', @$aref[$j]), "\"\n";
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Remember to post complete test programs. There might be something else that you are doing that's broken. Also "doesn't work" doesn't really tell us anything. What were you expecting to get and what did you get? Show us all output, error messages, warnings, and so on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works as far as you've gone. Adding some test data to your program gives us:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @aoaoh = (
    [
        { a => 1, b => 2 },
        { c => 3, d => 4 },
    ],
    [
        { a => 101, b => 102 },
        { c => 103, d => 104 },
    ],
);

for my $j (0 .. $#aoaoh) {
    for my $aref (@aoaoh) {
    print '"' . join('","', @$aref[$j]), "\"\n";
    }
}
```

And running that gives:

```
$ ./aoaoh 
"HASH(0x9c45818)"
"HASH(0x9c70c48)"
"HASH(0x9c60418)"
"HASH(0x9c70c08)"
```

So you've successfully navigated the two levels of arrays and you're just left with the hash references to dereference. Something like this perhaps:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @aoaoh = (
    [
        { a => 1, b => 2 },
        { c => 3, d => 4 },
    ],
    [
        { a => 101, b => 102 },
        { c => 103, d => 104 },
    ],
);

for my $j (0 .. $#aoaoh) {
    for my $aref (@aoaoh) {
        # print '"' . join('","', @$aref[$j]), "\"\n";
        for (keys %{$aref->[$j]}) {
            print "$_ -> $aref->[$j]{$_}\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives:

```
$ ./aoaoh 
a -> 1
b -> 2
a -> 101
b -> 102
c -> 3
d -> 4
c -> 103
d -> 104
```

Personally, I'd write it like this as I think it's easier to deal with elements than indexes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @aoaoh = (
    [
        { a => 1, b => 2 },
        { c => 3, d => 4 },
    ],
    [
        { a => 101, b => 102 },
        { c => 103, d => 104 },
    ],
);

for my $aref (@aoaoh) {
    for my $href (@$aref) {
        for (keys %{$href}) {
            print "$_ -> $href->{$_}\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach my $aoh (@aoaoh) {

    foreach my $hashref ( @{$aoh} ) {

        foreach my $key ( keys %{$hashref} ) {

            print $key . " => " . $hashref->{$key}, "\n";
        }

        print "#" x 40, "\n";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Sorry, it must be array (not array ref)

Answer (score 1):

To loop through the whole *kit & caboodle*:

```
use 5.012;
use warnings;

my @array = (
    [
        { a => 1, b => 2 },
        { c => 3, d => 4 },
    ],
    [
        { a => 101, b => 102 },
        { c => 103, d => 104 },
    ],
);

for my $root (@array) {
    for my $each_array_of_hashes (@$root) {
        for my $k (keys %{ $each_array_of_hashes } ) {
            say $k, ' => ', $each_array_of_hashes->{$k};
        }
    }
}
```

Is this what you're after?

Comment: If you are going to use `say`, please use one of the pragmas that turn it on.  Otherwise people will think your example is broken (because it is).

Comment: re: Chas comment.  If you have pre 5.10 version of Perl then look at `Perl::Say` CPAN module.  Otherwise amend `say` to `print` and postfix with a newline (ie. `print "some text\n";` as opposed to `say "some text";`

Comment: @Chas. Owens:  Have updated now.  Hopefully *people* won't think its now broken because they're not running on perl 5.12 :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at **[perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)**, it will help you,
and see the answer below.

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my @aoaoh = (
        [
            { a => 1, b => 2 },
            { c => 3, d => 4 },
        ],
        [
            { a => 101, b => 102 },
            { c => 103, d => 104 },
        ],
    );
    for my $j (0 .. $#aoaoh) {
        for my $aref (@{$aoaoh[$j]}) {
            for my $test (keys %{$aref})
            {
               print"$test => ${$aref}{$test}\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

output:

```
a => 1
b => 2
c => 3
d => 4
a => 101
b => 102
c => 103
d => 104
```